# Unicode character error (inputenc package)

Tags: fonts, unicode, input-encodings, newunicodechar

I'm trying to compile a file, but its returning an error about inputenc package.

MVE:

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % tamanho da fonte
a4paper, % tamanho do papel
hidelinks, % esconder links
english, % linguagem secundária
brazil, % linguagem primária
% twocolumn % duas colunas
]{article} % classe do documento

% --------- %
% PREÂMBULO %
% --------- %

% --------------- %
% Pacotes básicos %
% --------------- %

\usepackage{times} % fonte Helvetica
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % fonte sans-serif default
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % pacote de linguagem
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} % margens da folha
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indentação da primeira linha
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm} % espaçamento entre parágrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm} % indentação de 1,5 cm
\usepackage{graphicx} % utilização de gráficos no texto
\graphicspath{ {./Imagens/} } % local das imagens
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % reconhecimento de links
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc} % margens das notas de rodapé
\frenchspacing % otimização dos espaços
\usepackage{setspace} % alteração do espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage{lipsum} % utilização de dummy text

% ------------------ %
% Definições da capa %
% ------------------ %

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{center}
  \textbf{\@title}
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
  \@author
  \end{flushright}
\egroup
}
\makeatother

% ----- %
% Dados %
% ----- %

\title{RESTRIÇÕES VERTICAIS NA CADEIA DE COMERCIALIZAÇÃO DE ETANOL     
COMBUSTÍVEL: ANÁLISE DO IMPACTO CONCORRENCIAL DO PODER NORMATIVO 
E REGULADOR NO SETOR VAREJISTA}
\author{}
\date{}

% --------- %
% Traduções %
% --------- %

\renewenvironment{abstract}{\noindent\textbf{RESUMO}\normalsize}

% ------------------ %
% Cabeçalho e rodapé %
% ------------------ %

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% ------------------------ %
% Configurações das seções %
% ------------------------ %

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\sc\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
   \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

   % -------------------- %
   % Margens das citações %
   % -------------------- %

   \renewenvironment{quote}{\footnotesize\singlespacing\list{}%
      {\rightmargin=0cm \leftmargin=4cm}\item\relax}{\endlist}
```

The paragraph that is returning the error is the following one, inserted in quote environment:

```
35. Por sua vez, as bases são propriamente os ativos das distribuidoras, 
canalizando os fluxos ao longo de sua cadeia de operações. Elas são 
compostas basicamente por tanques de armazenamento, pátio e plataformas 
de carregamento e descarregamento dos modais de carga (dutos, vagões de 
trem, caminhões-tanque). Conforme será relatado em breve, a posse de 
bases com acesso a modais estratégicos na localidade pode ser um grande 
diferencial competitivo para uma distribuidora na competição em um 
corredor logístico. Antes de 2014, era possível a uma distribuidora 
entrar no mercado apenas arrendando espaço em bases alheias, sem possuir 
base própria. No entanto, com a edição da Resolução ANP n. 58/2014, as 
entrantes devem possuir propriedade, exclusiva ou compartilhada 
(condomínio), sobre 750 m³ de espaço em base que atenda aos requisitos 
da Resolução ANP n. 42/2011. [...]
```

When I run the compile, I get this error:

```
Artigo Formatado.tex (linha 295)
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ¬≥ (U+B3)
```

Comment: My money would be on the `750 m³`. *edit*: indeed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters You could use `siunitx` and write `\SI{750}{\cubic\metre}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+00B3 is superscript 3 so if you want to keep that you can define

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\textsuperscript{3}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, David. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are free to switch to either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you needn't worry anymore about utf8-encoded characters; just load the `fontspec` package and load a suitable text font via a `\setmainfont` directive. Since you're loading the `times` package in your example code, I would suggest you run `\setmainfont{XITS}`. (XITS is another Times Roman font clone.)

You may want to change the first part of the document preamble to

```
% --------- %
% PREÂMBULO %
% --------- %

% --------------- %
% Pacotes básicos %
% --------------- %

\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{XITS}
\else\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{XITS}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte encoding
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
  \usepackage{times} % fonte Times Roman
  %\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % fonte sans-serif default
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\textsuperscript{3}} % <-- new
\fi\fi
```

That way, you can switch back and forth between pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX and decide which typesetting engine works best satisfies your needs best.

Anyway, here's the output of the paragraph in question when compiled with LuaLaTeX; I've highlighted the output of `m³`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Mico. Haven't tried your answer, 'cause the upper one has worked, but I've got your output.